# Taking bitwise & of __be 32 type in Linux Kernel Module

Tags: c, linux, kernel, kernel-module, netfilter

The linux/ folder contains the ip.h header file, wherein part of the structure of IP header is defined as follows:

```
struct iphdr
{
     // ...
     __be32 saddr;
     __be32 daddr;
};
```

I have a situation wherein I have a source netmask of type char*. I want to check whether a IP address of type __be32 belongs to a network with address of type char*. I can convert netmask and network address to __be32 using in_aton() provided in linux/inet.h.

```
 char * network_addr = "192.166.0.0";
 char * netmask = "255.255.0.0";
```

Can someone please tell how can I take the boolean && of addresses being type __be32 or just applying && operator will give correct result.

Thanks.

Comment: Byte order doesn't matter for bitwise operators, as long as both operands use the same order.  Things need to line up, but place value makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the bitwise AND operator `&` and not the logical AND operator `&&`:

```
__be32 addr;
__be32 addr_mask;
...
__be32 addr_masked = addr & addr_mask;
```

Remember IPv4 adresses are 32-bit number: 4 x 8-bit bytes

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `__be32` is a 32-bit value in big-endian byte order, which might not match the host byte order.  Look for byte swapping routines like `be32toh` to convert to host byte order for your comparisons.

```
same_network = (my_addr & addr_mask) == (be32toh( his_addr_be) & addr_mask);
```

Comment: I converted all my values to __be32 and then performed comparison, so all values had same byte order